# OSL v3.0 - Can I sell my software based on OSL v3.0 code source?

Tags: licensing, osl-3.0

1. Can I sell my software based on OSL v3.0 code source?
2. Can I open the source code only for my customers?
3. Can I limit the my changes to original source code, that is, a customer can't sell, modify or redistribute this changes?

E.g. I want create own shop system based on PrestaShop, but with many modifications to it.

Comment: What research have you done to try to answer these questions yourself?

Comment: I checked https://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Software_License and http://rosenlaw.com/OSL3.0-explained.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSL 3.0 is a rather uncommon, less used open source license. It is in spirit similar to the AGPL licenses in that a usage in ["external deployments"](http://rosenlaw.com/OSL3.0-explained.htm#_Toc187293088) may trigger the license copyleft terms.

So in a nutshell, yes you can build a commercial software that is derived from OSL-licensed software and yes you can sell it. But as a derivative work, the software will still be subject to the OSL at large and in particular:

- you will have to redistribute the source code per section 3.
- customers that do an "external deployment" per [section 5](https://opensource.org/licenses/OSL-3.0) will have to redistribute the code "to the public" per section 1.c of the OSL 3.0
- customers will have the right to change and redistribute your changes under the OSL for free, or modify further or sell these per section 1.

Comment: So, I must publish the source code of my work, or I can let the access to source code only for my customers? For example, someone is not my customer, but he asks me for access to the source code - I MUST give him that access, or I CAN, but not must if he isn't my customer?

Comment: I think you can push the source only to your customers... But your customer may have redistribute it to anyone if the "externally deploy" as the OSL mention "to the public" as I explained in my answer